# How to get the probability of sequential events?

Tags: probability, independence

The following question comes from the logic puzzle by Dan Moore. A hunter only shoots one bullet on a deer, if he fails, he doesn't try again. The probability of shooting sucessfully is 1/4.
The question is: What is the probability of shooting 4 deers successfully and missing one.
I thought the correct answer would be: (1/4)^4 * 3/4
The correct solution is: (1/4)^4 * 3/4 * 5
My question: Why the need to multiply with 5? The probability of getting head by flipping the coin two times sequentially is 1/2 * 1/2 too.

Comment: *You are correct.* The hunter can fail only on the last shot as per stipulations. The book answer allows failure on any of the five shots.

Comment: The answer of $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4\cdot \frac{3}{4}$ is the probability of the sequence of events being: hit *then* hit *then* hit *then* hit *then* miss.  It does not account for other possibilities such as hit *then* miss *then* hit *then*...  For your coin metaphor, compare to the question of having gotten only one head and one tail in your two flips.  Compare the phrase "*shooting 4 deer successfully and missing one*" to the phrase "*shooting 4 deer successfully and* **then** *missing one*"

Comment: @JMoravitz it kinda covers other possbilities. For example hit,miss,hit,hit,hit would be 1/4*3/4*1/4*1/4*1/4 = 3/1024, so the same thing as (1/4)^4 * 3/4. The order has no influence.

Comment: The answer of $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4\cdot \frac{3}{4}$ is the probability of the sequence of events being very specifically HHHHM with the miss specifically at the end.  *It happens to also be* as a completely separate calculation the probability of the order specifically being HMHHH.  It happens to also be as a completely separate calculation the probability of the order specifically being HHHMH, and similarly for other possible orders.  Since all of those orders are all valid outcomes that count as "one deer missed and four deer hit (in some order)" we can add the results together

Comment: @JMoravitz: The question specifies "**A hunter only shoots one bullet on a deer, if he fails, he doesn't try again**."

Comment: I think the problem is phrased ambiguously.  I read the condition as applying to a single deer only.  That is to say, the hunter shoots exactly once at any given target deer.  You appear to be reading it as saying that the hunter keeps shooting a bunch of deer and stops when he has missed one.  The two readings give different results, as you have noticed.

Comment: In the end, this sounds like a question of language more than anything else.  The question being whether we are allowing for a miss to come in the middle of the hits or not.  If you do allow for a miss to come in the middle of the hits, then the answer is not just the probability of HHHHM... you must add to that the probabilities of MHHHH, HMHHH, HHMHH and HHHMH as well, which although these all are equal does not allow you to skip the step of adding them together.  It just makes adding them together easier.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, now I think you're correct. The solution covers all 5 possibilities, (1/4)^4 * 3/4 covers only one, so that's why multiply with 5.

Comment: You interpreted the question as *A hunter only shoots one bullet on a deer, if he fails, he doesn't try again **at all**.* The book seems to interpret it as *A hunter only shoots one bullet on a deer, if he fails, he doesn't try again **shooting the same deer**.*

Comment: @tevemadar to be clear, trueblue interpreted it the first way.  lulu and myself interpreted it the second way.  It has not been explicitly stated how the OP interpreted the problem however from the conversation thus far it sounds like the OP also interpreted it the second way but made incorrect calculations having skipped a step.  It is possible the OP interpreted the problem the first way in which case they would have been correct for their interpretation, however from "*it kinda covers other possibilities for example hit,miss,hit,hit,hit*" I read that as OP thinking that a valid outcome

Comment: @JMoravitz, I meant the remark for OP. That's why there were no @-s inside.

Comment: @tevemadar yes, and I'm saying that your comment is incorrect, having incorrectly evaluated the situation and come to the incorrect conclusion of how it was that the OP had interpreted things

Comment: @JMoravitz Indeed, I interpreted the question the same way as you did, but made the mistake of not taking in the various possibilities, leading to incorrect calculation.

Comment: @0ut0n0my: By the way, did you reproduce the question **exactly** or just sort of paraphrase it ?

Comment: @trueblueanil the book is in german, the translation would be: "what are the chances that he fires five shots and four of them hit a deer?"

Comment: @0ut0n0my: Then it is very clear that a multiplier of $5$ is needed !

Answer (score 1):

As the hunter stops shooting after a miss, the last shot must necessarily be a miss. So you are correct. The answer is

$$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4 \times \frac{3}{4}$$

You may want to recheck if you have stated the problem correctly.

Note that if the miss didn’t necessarily have to be the last shot, there would be $5$ positions where it could be placed, which would then correspond to the textbook answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since order is not important, arrangement of $5$ shooting if $4$ of them hit the target is $\frac{5!}{4!\times 1!}$

$\text{P}= \frac{5!}{4!\times 1!}\times (\frac{1}{4})^4\times \frac{3}{4}$